# How can you set the HDMI resolution of the Raspberry Pi Zero W to 320x240?

Tags: hdmi, desktop

Bought one of those cheapo HDMI LED projectors which has HDMI input but only a native resolution of 320x240. Internally it down-samples.

I'm wondering if the Pi Zero W can be configured to output at that native resolution so no down-sampling would be needed.

Note: I actually don't need--or even want--the full Raspbian Desktop so I'm not worried about how that UI won't look correct with such a small resolution.  The ultimate goal is to have only a single, full-screen app and nothing else since the Pi will be embedded inside the projector, which together will be used as an information appliance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit the /boot/config.txt file and add the following :

```
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_cvt=320 240 60 1 0 0 0
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=87
```

For reference :

```
hdmi_force_hotplug=1 Use HDMI mode even if no HDMI monitor is detected

hdmi_cvt=<width> <height> <framerate> <aspect> <margins> <interlace> <rb>
width        width in pixels
height       height in pixels
framerate    framerate in Hz
aspect       aspect ratio 1=4:3, 2=14:9, 3=16:9, 4=5:4, 5=16:10, 6=15:9
margins      0=margins disabled, 1=margins enabled
interlace    0=progressive, 1=interlaced
rb           0=normal, 1=reduced blanking

hdmi_group=2 hdmi type DMT
hdmi_mode=87 custom mode
```

Comment: Before I mark this as accepted, can you please comment on what each entry does?  That will make a better reference for others coming here for the same reasons.

Comment: Answer edited, comments added

Comment: Perfect!  Great answer for others too!